# galería con librería f4ncybox

Tags: javascript, jquery

No puedo lograr que la imagen principal se abra (f4ncybox) al hacer clic sobre ella.
La imagen a la que me refiero es a la que esta en el tag main. Los thumbnails de la izquierda son la galería, y quiero que al estar una seleccionada como la principal, al dar clic sobre ella se abra con la librería f4ncybox.
La pasarela de las imagenes funciona bien, si se selecciona cualquiera de las tres imagenes del lado izquierdo se muestra bien como la imagen principal, lo que no ocurre es que al dar clic sobre la imagen principal se abra.
Alguien me podrá ayudar con mi código?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://datoweb.com/visor/js/fresco/fresco.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datoweb.com/visor/css/fresco/fresco.css" />

<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0/dist/fancybox.css"
    />
    <style>
        .wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
        text-align: center;
        }

        .image-gallery {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        }

        .primary,
        .thumbnails {
        display: table-cell;
        }

        .thumbnails {
        width: 300px;

        }

        .primary {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #cccccc;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .thumbnail:hover .thumbnail-image, .selected .thumbnail-image {
        border: 4px solid red;
        }

        .thumbnail-image {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 4px solid transparent;
        }
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>


<div class="wrapper">
<header>
  <h1>Product Image Gallery with Thumbnails</h1>
  <p>Click on the thumbnail to view it larger on the right!</p>
</header>

<div class="image-gallery">
  <aside class="thumbnails">
    <a href="#" class="selected thumbnail" data-big="http://placekitten.com/420/600">
      <div class="thumbnail-image" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/420/600)"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-big="http://placekitten.com/450/600">
      <div class="thumbnail-image" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/450/600)"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-big="http://placekitten.com/460/700">
      <div class="thumbnail-image" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/460/700)"></div>
    </a>
  </aside>

  <main class="primary" data-fancybox="image-gallery" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/420/600');"></main>
</div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0/dist/fancybox.umd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.thumbnail').on('click', function() {
        var clicked = $(this);
        var newSelection = clicked.data('big');
        var $img = $('.primary').css("background-image","url(" + newSelection + ")");
            clicked.parent().find('.thumbnail').removeClass('selected');
            clicked.addClass('selected');
        $('.primary').empty().append($img.hide().fadeIn('slow'));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```